# Spring Batch sub job processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a working spring job that contains a single Tasklet. However, I want to refactor it and switch to a multi-step job.
I need to create an ordered file with many header records containing users info followed by user custom information such as addresses and bills.

The output file is so structured:

```
r1:  user info
r2:  user addresses
r3:  user bill1
r4:  user bill2
r5:  ...
r6:  user billN
r7:  user2 info
r8:  user2 addresses
r9:  user2 bill1
r10: user2 biil2
r11: ...
```

The user info, address, and the user bills are retrieved from 3 different postgres tables.

Is there any change to refactoring this project using the Steplets since the file records must be ordered and the number of bills per user is unknown?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pattern and is described in the [driving query section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) of the reference documentation.

The idea is to make your item reader read records from the user table, and add an item processor to enrich items with other details.